# R: cor.test by group with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to calculate the correlation between two numeric columns in a data frame for each level of a factor. Here is an example data frame:

```
concentration <-(c(3, 8, 4, 7, 3, 1, 3, 3, 8, 6))
area <-c(0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7)
area_type <-c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
data_frame <-data.frame(concentration, area, area_type)
```

In this example, I want to calculate the correlation between concentration and area for each level of area_type. I want to use cor.test rather than cor because I want p-values and kendall tau values.  I have tried to do this using ddply:

```
ddply(data_frame, "area_type", summarise,
  corr=(cor.test(data_frame$area, data_frame$concentration,
                 alternative="two.sided", method="kendall") ) )
```

However, I am having a problem with the output: it is organized differently from the normal Kendall cor.test output, which states z value, p-value, alternative hypothesis, and tau estimate. Instead of that, I get the output below. I don't know what each row of the output indicates. In addition, the output values are the same for each level of area_type.

```
  area_type                                         corr
1          A                                    0.3766218
2          A                                         NULL
3          A                                    0.7064547
4          A                                    0.1001252
5          A                                            0
6          A                                    two.sided
7          A               Kendall's rank correlation tau
8          A data_frame$area and data_frame$concentration
9          B                                    0.3766218
10         B                                         NULL
11         B                                    0.7064547
12         B                                    0.1001252
13         B                                            0
14         B                                    two.sided
15         B               Kendall's rank correlation tau
16         B data_frame$area and data_frame$concentration
```

What am I doing wrong with ddply? Or are there other ways of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an additional column with the names of corr. Also, your syntax is slightly incorrect. The `.` specifies that the variable is from the data frame you've specified. Then remove the data_frame$ or else it will use the entire data frame:

`ddply(data_frame, .(area_type), summarise,
      corr=(cor.test(area, concentration,
                     alternative="two.sided", method="kendall")), name=names(corr) )`

Which gives:

```
   area_type                           corr        name
1          A                      -0.285133   statistic
2          A                           NULL   parameter
3          A                      0.7755423     p.value
4          A                     -0.1259882    estimate
5          A                              0  null.value
6          A                      two.sided alternative
7          A Kendall's rank correlation tau      method
8          A         area and concentration   data.name
9          B                              6   statistic
10         B                           NULL   parameter
11         B                      0.8166667     p.value
12         B                            0.2    estimate
13         B                              0  null.value
14         B                      two.sided alternative
15         B Kendall's rank correlation tau      method
16         B         area and concentration   data.name
```

statistic is the z-value and estimate is the tau estimate.

EDIT: You can also do it like this to only pull what you want:

```
corfun<-function(x, y) {
  corr=(cor.test(x, y,
                 alternative="two.sided", method="kendall"))
}

ddply(data_frame, .(area_type), summarise,z=corfun(area,concentration)$statistic,
      pval=corfun(area,concentration)$p.value,
      tau.est=corfun(area,concentration)$estimate,
      alt=corfun(area,concentration)$alternative
      )
```

Which gives:

`area_type         z      pval    tau.est       alt
1         A -0.285133 0.7755423 -0.1259882 two.sided
2         B  6.000000 0.8166667  0.2000000 two.sided`

Comment: Your suggestion does help label the output. However, there is still the problem that the statistics are the same fore each level of area_type. The correlation results should be different for each level of area_type in this example. So there is still apparently something wrong with how I am using ddply.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't notice that part. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason this is not working is the cor.test returns:

```
Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  data_frame$concentration and data_frame$area
t = 0.5047, df = 8, p-value = 0.6274
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.5104148  0.7250936
sample estimates:
  cor 
  0.1756652
```

This information cannot be put into a data.frame (which ddply does) without future complicating the code. If you can provide the exact information you need then I can provide further assistance. I would look at just using

```
corrTest <- ddply(.data = data_frame, 
                 .variables = .(area_type), 
                 .fun = cor(concentration, area,))
                                method="kendall")))
```

I haven't test this code but this is the route I would take initially and work from here.

Comment: I want to output the statistic (z-value), p-value, and estimate (tau) for each level of area_type.